# Return async value from Fable.Remoting

Tags: f#, fable-f#, elmish

Here is a client side Fable.Remoting example that prints the result of an async function.

```ml
    // Client code (Compiled to Javascript using Fable)
    // ============
    open Fable.Remoting.Client

    let server = Proxy.create<IServer>

    async {
     let! length = server.getLength “hello”
     do printfn “%d” length // 5
    }
    |> Async.StartImmediate
```

How do I get the `length` value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see you've tagged your question with [elmish](/questions/tagged/elmish), so I'm going to assume you have a `Msg` type defined. Don't use `Async.StartImmediate` or `Async.RunSynchronously`; in Elmish, you should use [`Cmd.OfAsync`](https://elmish.github.io/elmish/cmd.html) to schedule a message to be dispatched once the async block returns a value. There are four functions in `Cmd.OfAsync` (and the same four appear in `Cmd.OfPromise` as well): `either`, `perform`, `attempt`, and `result`. I'll break them down for you since their documentation isn't quite up to snuff yet:

- `either`: takes four parameters, `task`, `arg`, `ofSuccess`, and `ofError`. `task` is the async function you want to call (of type `'a -> Async<'b>`). `arg` is the parameter of type `'a` that you want to pass to the `task` function. `ofSuccess` is a function of type `'b -> 'Msg`: it will receive the result of the async function and is supposed to create a message, presumably one that incorporates the `'b` result. Finally, `ofError` is a function of type `exn -> 'Msg`: if the `task` function throws an exception, then `ofError` will be called instead of `ofSuccess`, and is supposed to turn that exception into an Elmish message that your code can handle (presumably one that will log an error to the Javascript console or pop up a notification with [Thoth.Toast](https://mangelmaxime.github.io/Thoth/elmish/toast_docs.html) or something like that).
- `perform`: like `either` but there's no `ofError` parameter. Use this if your async command cannot fail (which is never the case with remote API calls, as it's always possible the network is down or your server is unresponsive), or if you just don't care about exceptions and don't mind an unhandled exception getting thrown.
- `attempt`: like `either` but there's no `ofSuccess` parameter, so the `task` function's result will be ignored if it succeeds.
- `result`: this one is completely different. It just takes a single parameter of type `Async<'Msg>`, i.e. you pass it an `async` block that is already going to produce a message.

With the code you've written, you would use `Cmd.OfAsync.result` if you wanted to make minimal changes to your code, but I would suggest using `Cmd.OfAsync.perform` instead (and upgrading it to `Cmd.OfAsync.either` once you have written some error-handling code). I'll show you both ways:

```
type Msg =
    // ... rest of your messages go here
    | GetLength of string
    | LengthResult of int

let update msg model =
    match msg with
    // ... rest of your update function
    | GetLength s ->
        let usePerform = true
        if usePerform then
            model, Cmd.OfAsync.perform server.getLength s LengthResult
        else
            let length : Async<Msg> = async {
                let! length = server.getLength s
                return (LengthResult length)
            }
            model, Cmd.OfAsync.result length
    | LengthResult len ->
        // Do whatever you needed to do with the API result
        printfn "Length was %d" len
        model, Cmd.none
```

And if you were using `either` (which you really should do once you go to production), there would be a third message `LogError of exn` that would be handled like:

```
    | LogError e ->
        printfn "Error: %s" e.Message
        model, Cmd.none
```

and the `Cmd.OfAsync.perform` line in the code above would become:

```
        model, Cmd.OfAsync.either server.getLength s LengthResult LogError
```

That's the *right* way to handle async-producing functions in Elmish.

Answer (score 4):

Async is one of the places where you use `return` in F#. So you need to return the length value. Also, `Async.StartImmediate` returns `()` (unit). Use something else, e.g. `Async.RunSynchronously` if you need the extracted value. Depends on what you need to achieve with it.

```
let length = 
    async {
         let! length = async {return String.length "hello"}
         do printfn "%d" length // 5
         return length
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously

length // val it : int = 5
```

Btw, you mention fable. So you might be able to use JS `promise`.

Some resources on Async in F#:

[F# Async Guide from Jet](https://medium.com/jettech/f-async-guide-eb3c8a2d180a)

[Async Programming](https://hub.packtpub.com/asynchronous-programming-f/)

[FSharp for Fun and Profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/)

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/asynchronous-and-concurrent-programming/async)

[C# and F# Async](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-fsharp-async-intro.aspx/)

Comment: The OP is using Elmish, which means there are better ways to handle this than Async.RunSynchronously. Elmish has some nice helper functions for handling asyncs and promises.

Comment: Ah, great, I suspected as much. Hope someone can chime in!

Comment: `Async.RunSynchronously` is what I was looking for, but it looks like it's not available in Fable: `export 'runSynchronously' was not found in '../../.fable/fable-library.2.3.12/Async.js`. I don't think I can use the `promise` computation expression because the return value of functions in Fable Remoting is `Async<'t>`.

Comment: @BrettRowberry you might want to check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to call from js code.

```
// Client code (Compiled to Javascript using Fable)
// ============
open Fable.Remoting.Client
open Fable.Core // required for Async.StartAsPromise 


let server = Proxy.create<IServer>
let len_from_fable () = 
    async {
         let! length = server.getLength “hello”
         return length
    } |> Async.StartAsPromise
```

call from js

```js
    async func() {
        let len = await len_from_fable()
        print(len)
    }
```

works in fable 3.0.